# Snowflake Copy component in Azure Data factory cannot default a column timestamp

Tags: azure-data-factory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have been able to copy a file directly from Azure blob storage to Snowflake into a table.  I have one column that i defaulted to current timestamp to store when the data was imported.  This field however is ending up as null even though i have it defaulted.  anyone have ideas on how to do this?  there isn't a post script i can run with this component.

Comment: Can you share your table DDL and your COPY INTO statement?

Comment: @Kirby I'm aware.  I was interested in seeing the COPY INTO statement that was being generated.